# Fetching data from backend to create a dropdown list in Javascript

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Here is my course container snippet. I want to create a dropdown list of all the courses by fetching data from the backend (URL: https://ffcc-app.herokuapp.com/get/courses)
In the snippet, I have manually put some dummy courses

```html
<div class="container">
        <form action="#" method="POST">
        <h2>Course 1</h2>
        <div class="select-box">
          <div class="options-container">
            <div class="option">
                <input type="radio" class="radio" id="film" name="category" value="film" />
                <label for="Course 2">Course 1</label>
              </div>
            <div class="option">
              <input type="radio" class="radio" id="dance" name="category" value="dance" />
              <label for="Course 2">Course 2</label>
            </div>
            <div class="option">
              <input type="radio" class="radio" id="science" name="category" value="science" />
              <label for="Course 3">Course 3</label>
            </div>
            <div class="option">
              <input type="radio" class="radio" id="art" name="category" value="art"/>
              <label for="Course 4">Course 4</label>
            </div>
            <div class="option">
              <input type="radio" class="radio" id="music" name="category" value="music"/>
              <label for="Course 5">Course 5</label>
            </div> 
            
          </div>
          <div class="selected">
            Select Courses
          </div>
          <div class="search-box">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." />
          </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

I have created a search box to filter the course list and display the filtered list when you type any character.
**When you select any course it should replace "Selected" class value with the selected course's name**

I tried to fetch data from the backend using Fetch API, here is my code snippet

```js
const point = 'https://ffcc-app.herokuapp.com/get/courses';

let courses1 =[];

fetch(point)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => courses1=data.courses)

function findMatches(wordToMatch , courses1){
    return courses1.filter(function place(a){
        const regex = new RegExp(wordToMatch,'gi')
        return a.code.match(regex) || a.title.match(regex)
    });
}

function displayMatches(){
    const matchArray = findMatches(this.value, courses1)
    const html = matchArray.map(place => {
        const regex = new RegExp(this.value, 'gi');
        const code = place.code.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
        const title = place.title.replace(regex, `<span class="hl">${this.value}</span>`);
        return `
        <div class="option">
              <input type="radio" class="radio" name="category" />
              <label for="course-1"> ${code} , ${title} , ${place.credits} , ${place.type}</label>
        </div>
        `
    }).join("");
    opt.innerHTML = html;
}
const search = document.querySelector(".search-box");
const opt = document.querySelector(".options-container");
search.addEventListener("change",displayMatches);
search.addEventListener("keyup",displayMatches);
```

Though I am able to fetch it, I am not getting my desired output, also I cannot figure out a way to replace the "Selected" class value with the courses' value.

Can someone help me in this? I would appreciate it if you also used Fetch API for fetching the data.

Comment: Can you give more details on what happens ? What do you see instead of the "desired output". My first guess would be that the 'courses1' array is not yet ready when you try to use it. Are you getting any error messages ?

Comment: No I am not getting any error messages as such instead I am getting all the 1514 courses list but when I type any character, it is not getting filtered and also I am not able to replace the "Selected" class value with the course's name.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough time to give you a full solution or detailed explanation, but I hope this can help you get started:
It's a working example that fetches the data, and filters through it, and returns courses whose title or code match a search string (which I think is what your code had trouble with)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script>
    const endpoint = 'https://ffcc-app.herokuapp.com/get/courses';
    let courses = [];

    // if you don't know about async/await, check it out, it's pretty neat!
    async function main() {
      const response = await fetch(endpoint);
      const data = await response.json();
      courses = data.courses;

      console.log(findCourses("Lean Start-up Management"));
    }

    function findCourses(search) {
      const norm_search = search.toLowerCase();
      return courses.filter(course => {
        return course.title.toLowerCase().includes(norm_search) ||
               course.code.toLowerCase().includes(norm_search);
      })
    }

    main();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```